# nightbot slap command with variable output

Tags: twitch

TLDR: i need a nightbot command with 2 varying outputs. I.E.: "user slapped user with [random item here]! [random pain response here]"

ok so im very new when it comes to java script. i recently got very into attempting to make interactive commands for nightbot for my twitch as to engage the viewers more! my issue is i can not figure out how to make a command that begins !slap @touser, when the command is executed, id like it to respond with "user slapped user with [enter random item here] [random pain response here]". im not sure if it can be done but, would greatly appreciate the assistance and anything that could be taught would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to edit Nightbot with code in your channel? If you are looking for random responses, then it might be; `let randomItems = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]; let randomPains = ["pain1", "pain2", "pain3"]; let responseItem = randomItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomItems.length)]; let responsePain = randomPains[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomPains.length)]` that's how you get random items on javascript.

Comment: thank you that is perfect! on the nightbot website you can edit its commands directly and it has a textbox you can use to enter code or other command prompts into